# How to put a scrollView in a particular area of a view and put a label in it using Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to put a small scrollView in an existing view and then use it to show a label, which according to the length of the text I can automatically set the scrolling action. I put a scrollView and then out a view in that. Then I added a label in it but am unable to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help the community answer your question, could you please add a bit more details? Specifically: a) Are you using a storyboard/XIB or doing everything in code? Please describe what constraints have you added to your views or add your code. b) What exactly is the desired outcome? Please clarify what "automatically set the scrolling action" means.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need Scroll View if u only want to make label height dynamic.
otherwise use a scrollview take an outlet of scrollview's height and manage it programmatically as per the height of the content.